# Static members variables can be used only in static methods of class, but why we can assign value to static variable inside constructor of C++ class?

Tags: c++, constructor, static

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
class Player
{
private:
    static int next_id;
public:
    static int getID() { return next_id; }
    Player(int x) { **next_id = x;** }
};

int Player::next_id = 0;
 
int main()
{
  Player p1(1);
  cout << p1.getID() << " ";
  Player p2(2);
  cout << p2.getID() << " ";
  Player p3(3);
  cout << p3.getID();
  return 0;
}
```

Constructor is not static function, even we are able to assign value to static variable.
Here we should get compile error. But its running fine with below output.
Output:1 2 3

Comment: "Static members variables can be used only in static methods of class" where did you read that?

Comment: note that `**` cannot be used in code formatting, use a comment instead to highlight some code

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar If you will remove the word "only" the title of your question will be more or less correct.:)

Comment: I think you're confusing this with how non-static member variables can only  be used in non-static member functions. The point of static member variables is that they are shared among all instances.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Player
{
private:
    inline static int next_id;
public:
    static int getID() { return next_id; }
    Player(int x) { next_id = x; }
};



int main()
{
  Player p1(1);
  cout << p1.getID() << " ";
  Player p2(2);
  cout << p2.getID() << " ";
  Player p3(3);
  cout << p3.getID();
  return 0;
}
```

Add inline.